# Trabajar datos no preparados para trabajar juntos

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

Buen día, esta pregunta me es algo complicada de explicar, pero haré lo mejor que pueda.
Tengo un proyecto en el cuál debo obtener datos de distintas sucursales de mi empresa, por cada sucursal, es una base de datos (tienen la misma estructura, por eso no hay problema).
Mi problema radica en que, las bases de datos de cada sucursal **no estaban preparadas para ser trabajadas en conjunto**, es decir, aunque la estructura es la misma, los datos no se prepararon para ello, o en pocas palabras:

> el cliente 10 de la sucursal 1, no es el mismo que el cliente 10 de la
>   sucursal 2

entonces, al momento de querer aplicar llaves primarias en mis tablas, tengo el problema que, tengo ID's repetidos, aunque no precisamente significan que son datos duplicados, ya que vienen de distintas sucursales.

Lo primero en lo que pensé, fue en crear un campo más para manejarlo como ID interno, pero en mi oficina me comentaron que esa opción no es viable para nada.

Entonces, estaba pensando en crear una tabla llamada sucursales, que obtenga datos de la sucursal, y tener la opción para identificar de donde vienen los datos, agregando en cada tabla un campo que sirva como llave foránea para esa tabla sucursal. lo que no me parece buena idea, es que la dichosa tabla sucursales tenga 30 relaciones para todas las demás tablas del sistema. Con todo esto ya explicado, la pregunta es:

**¿Cuál es la mejor opción para trabajar con estos datos? necesito identificarlos como únicos, y saber de qué sucursal vienen**

Comment: Ambas ideas son buenas y depende de que te interese hacer. Si quieres eliminar duplicados, es mejor usar una clave sustituta para consolidar los datos de ciertas tablas. Si no importa tener duplicados, entonces puede ser más fácil agregar la sucursal a todas las tablas y tener una tabla de sucursales. No te preocupes por la cantidad de llaves foráneas.

Comment: no me importan los duplicados porque en si, sólo se repiten los ID's, no los demás datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad tienes muy buenas ideas, te comento mi caso en mi lugar de trabajo talvez te ayude a tomar una mejor decisión.

En nuestra empresa tenemos filiales, Filial El Salvador, Filial Mexico, Filial Guatemala etc etc. En cada una de ellas tenemos diferentes tipos de Clientes Clientes Locales, Clientes Exteriores, Proveedores etc. El caso es que un mismo Cliente a la vez puede ser un Proveedor.

La solución a este caso teniendo en cuenta que Tienes **Sucursal_1** **Cliente: Cod. 10** y **Sucursal_2** **Cliente: Cod. 10** que se diferencian por La sucursal tomar en cuenta como primer campo diferente, tomando en cuenta esto puedes crear una agrupación de Clientes que se refiera a la Sucursal de la que provienen aunque estos posean el mismo tipo de codigo conllevaran diferente tipo de agrupación.

Saludos.